# ReactJS uploading and reading any file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, upload

I am currently working on a react app that interacts with the ethereum blockchain, and I need to let a user upload a file and I wanna be able to read the binary data of the file to then hash it. I have looked into HTML5's FileReader and tried all the proposed solutions, but in vain. I am only able to get the File object but cannot read its binary data.

Has anyone got some experience with this ? I am fairly new to react and need some advice for this.

thanks

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: Have you tried FileReader s  readAsBinaryString method  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString

Comment: Please add what failed when you attempted to resolve this. Just saying you tried in vain is not enough.

Comment: Here is what i tried:
FileReader readAsArrayBuffer() after having fetched the file via <input> tag like described in react js doc 
I have also tried multiple npm modules but non has worked (react-file-reader, react-file-reader-input and others..)